# Do items in Far Cry 3 become very expensive later on?

Tags: far-cry-3

I just started playing the game today. I'm two hours in, and I already have about 1500+ dollars! I feel that it's really easy to get money with looting, selling items, mini quests, etc. Also, in the guide it says that some stores will sell weapons for free!

So, do you usually get to feel the scarcity of money in the game eventually? Basically, do items become expensive or anything like that? Do you ever really need to do quests to get some specific weapons or expensive items that cannot be obtained unless you really have a lot of money?

I was expecting the game to be more of a survival type game, where money really matters and it's not easy to become 'rich' so quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No, the prices of items stay the same throughout the game. However, there are some very expensive items available later in the game (the Signature Weapons), and I did find myself short of cash a few times when those weapons were unlocked.

By the mid-game, I was basically only spending money on 3 things (other than ammo refills):

- Treasure maps
- Weapon upgrades
- Signature weapons

There is unlimited money available in the game, as long as you leave at least one enemy outpost uncaptured so that enemies will respawn, you can keep killing them over and over again.

Comment: There is unlimited money even if you complete every outpost, you just have to be good at poker, target shooting, or the Trials of the Rakyat.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will ease up on looting as I quickly make money this way (along with capturing outposts and mini-quests).

Answer (score 2):

Money is basically a non-necessity.

When you capture a Radio Tower, you are given access to several new weapons free of charge. Some specific weapons, as well as weapon mods, will cost you a small amount of money.

Money can be quickly made by selling plants, or loot from various slain enemies. If you don't focus on hunting and crafting, you will quickly cap out your wallet.

A few ways to spend your money are:

- Buying weapons, weapon mods, and paint colors
- Buying maps - showing you either relic locations or treasure locations (for more money)
- Poker
- There is an achievement/trophy for reaching a specific amount, and this may require a bunch of money if you have never played

Answer (score 0):

Ammunition becomes a lot more expensive when you unlock the second island. I didn't realize that unlocking the second island would suddenly unlock tons of new weapons and raise the prices for ammunition so I was caught with too little money to fully resupply my ammo the first time I was out on the second island because I had basically forced myself to spend all my money on the first island because I thought I had unlocked everything and my wallet was reaching capacity so I spent money by buying every upgrade and every color scheme just to burn up money.

It cost over a thousand dollars just to resupply my ammo after doing nothing more than freeing my first 2 outposts on the second island and having a few random encounter engagements.